# Replacing Moen 1225 cartridge - entire stem and top of cartridge came out - bottom did not

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I'm the homeowner/landlord - I've changed the 1225 cartridges before with no problem....until tonight.

It has the Chateau style handle. Needed a little CLR to loosen screw but it came out. Cartridge came out with very little effort. Then I noticed the bottom was not attached!! Top and entire stem came of cartridge - the bottom pulled away and is STUCK.

I left it for the night with a rag drenched with CLR stuffed in with the remaining cartridge.

There was a lot of calcium build up on the inside of the handle but the CARTRIDGE itself looked like every other picture of an old cartridge.
HELP - this is a rental unit. I had some "little things" to fix and decide to updated smoke detectors while there ($300). I rent the house to my best friend - fortunately didn't freak out that the water is turned off overnight.

Any advice? I need to fix this asap and get the water on. A big $$ hit from a plumber will wipe me out for the month.

Comment: Could you turn the water off at the under-cabinet valves and at least get the water back on in the rest of the house?

Answer (score 2):

The new cartridges come with a plastic "key" that you are supposed to use after pulling the retaining clip but before attempting to remove the cartridge. This loosens the barrel/sleeve to help ensure that it comes out when you pull.

Since you did not use it (or you *did* but the barrel/sleeve still got stuck), you will likely need to rent or buy a special puller tool. The good ones are expensive ($80) to buy but good plumbing shops rent them. Ask around plumbing and hardware shops (not the "big box" stores) to find somewhere that rents a "Moen Puller". Mine looks like this:

[image]